# X3D to XML conversion

Tags: java, xml, x3d

I have dozens of X3D files and I'm aiming to use an XML parser to get them into a Java application. However, I know it might sound silly, but how would I convert the `.x3d` files into `.xml` files? The `.x3d` files were supplied to me from a friend in aim to make a 3D model viewer. I've done some research but I don't know if the following code is correct in loading X3D into XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE X3D PUBLIC "ISO//Web3D//DTD X3D 3.0//EN"
  "http://www.web3d.org/specifications/x3d-3.0.dtd">

<X3D profile="IMMERSIVE" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.web3d.org/specifications/x3d-   3.0.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name='filename' content='RedSphereBlueBox.x3d'/>
    </head>
        <Scene>
            <Transform>
                <NavigationInfo headlight='false' 
         avatarSize='0.25 1.6 0.75' type='EXAMINE'/>
                <DirectionalLight/>
                <Transform translation='3.0 0.0 1.0'>
                    <Shape>
                        <Sphere radius='2.3'/>
                        <Appearance>
                            <Material diffuseColor='1.0 0.0 0.0'/>
                        </Appearance>
                    </Shape>
                </Transform>
                <Transform translation='-2.4 0.2 1.0' rotation='0.0 0.707 0.707 0.9'>
                <Shape>
                    <Box/>
                    <Appearance>
                        <Material diffuseColor='0.0 0.0 1.0'/>
                    </Appearance>
                </Shape>
            </Transform>
        </Transform>
    </Scene>
</X3D>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also rename a .x3d file to .xml if that helps a native-XML tool deal with it.

The X3D Example Archives also provide copies of every scene in Canonical XML form, which supports application of XML Security tools for XML Digital Signature (authentication) and XML Encryption (privacy).  More on these topics at

- http://www.web3d.org/x3d/content/examples/X3dResources.html#Examples
- view-source:http://www.web3d.org/x3d/content/examples/HelloWorldCanonical.xml
- http://www.web3d.org/documents/specifications/19776-3/V3.3/Part03/concepts.html#X3DCanonicalForm
- http://www.web3d.org/x3d/content/examples/X3dResources.html#Security

Answer (score 0):

[X3D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X3D) is a file format based on XML, so yes: you will be able to load X3D files with a (Java) XML parser.

Comment: I am going to be using an XML parser to do so, but is the way shown above the correct way to do it? And would I have to save it as a `.xml`?

Comment: The file does not need to have the extension `.xml`. You haven't shown any code but just included an example of a X3D file.

Comment: So having an XML parser would work fine with the extension `.x3d`? I saw that online when I was doing research into how to convert `.x3d` formats into `.xml` formats and thought that that was the way.

Comment: @smitthy from time to time you should simply try something

Comment: Thanks for the help @wero was really appreciated :)